# Primitive elements of finite field

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, finite-fields

I've constructed a finite field as follows $K = F_3 [x] / (x^3-x+1) $.

Now my question is: How can I find primitive elements of my $K$?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Hint: If $\alpha$ is a zero of $x^3-x+1$, then $\alpha^3=\alpha-1$, and consequently $\alpha^9=\alpha^3-1=\alpha-2=\alpha+1$. So 
$$\alpha^{13}=\alpha^{1+3+9}=\cdots.$$ Anyway, the order of $\alpha$ must be a factor of $3^3-1=26$.

Comment: If we denote $f(x)=x^3-x-1$, then your polynomial is $-f(-x)$. The linked thread shows that a zero of $f(x)$ has order $13$. Zeros of your polynomial are the negatives of those of $f$.